# Active state from v-list-item stuck to false on load - Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to override the active state of the v-list-item but it doesnt work. I can print the input-value correctly, but the active state is stuck to false no matter what.

```
<v-list-item-group multiple> 
    <template v-for="(business, index) in getNearbyBusiness">
        <v-list-item
            :key="index"
            :input-value="business.business.business_projects[0].is_business_shortlisted"
        >
            <template v-slot:default="{ active }">
                <v-list-item-content></v-list-item-content>

                <v-list-item-action class="mr-3">
                    <p>{{ business.business.business_projects[0].is_business_shortlisted }}</p> // Prints correct value
                    <p>{{ active }}</p> // Stuck to false on load
            </template>
        </v-list-item>
    </template>
</v-list-item-group>
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

My thinking about this was entirely wrong.

You need to pass the `value` property on `v-list-item-group` and pass an array with indexes of the active `v-list-item`s.

e.g. `[1,4,5]` means that items with indexes 1,4,5 are active.